# GPS is ON permanently after proximity alert is set

Tags: android, android-location

I want my app to use proximity alerts. I figured out how to do that, alerts work as expected, but there's a problem - immediately after I set proximity alert, GPS icon appears in the status bar and stays there until I reboot my device (or turn off GPS, but it appears again as soon as I turn GPS back on).

The icon stays there even if I remove the alert (it is not fired anymore, so removing seems to work). My first thought was that it would be removed as soon as it gets location fix, but I was wrong.

This is reproduced on my Nexus S running vanilla 4.1.2 Jelly Bean (flashed factory image from Google, not even rooted) and on 4.1.2 emulator.

I also noticed that it doesn't seem to affect battery, device goes to sleep mode normally.

Here's the related code:

```
public void set(Context context) {
    LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, prepareIntent(context), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    double lat=getLocation().getGeoPoint().getLatitudeE6()/1e6;
    double lng=getLocation().getGeoPoint().getLongitudeE6()/1e6;
    locationManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lng, radius, -1, pendingIntent);
}

public void unset(Context context) {
    LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, prepareIntent(context), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    locationManager.removeProximityAlert(pendingIntent);
}
```

What could be the problem? How do I fix this?

---

**UPDATE:** I've run a little experiment (50 minutes of sleep mode with proximity alarm set), but results are rather confusing:

[image]

Seems like the icon is present, but GPS is not on all the time.

Can somebody clarify this situation?